# How to formulate systems of equations as a convex optimization problem?

Tags: systems-of-equations, convex-optimization, cvxpy

I have the following set of equations:

\begin{align*}
&\alpha_t \cdot (1-\theta) + \beta_t\cdot \theta = c_t \; \quad t = 1, \dots, T\\
&{\beta_t \cdot \theta^2 \over \alpha_t \cdot (1-\theta)^2 + \beta_t \cdot \theta^2} = k_t\; \quad t=1, \dots, T\\
&\sum_t^T \alpha_t = \sum_t^T \beta_t = 1\\
& 0 < \theta < 1
\end{align*}
where $c_t$ and $k_t$ are constants, $\sum_t c_t = 1$, and we want to solve for $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_T, \theta, \beta_1, \dots, \beta_T$. I want to solve the above equations using `cvxpy` but I'm not sure how to formulate the above into the form `cvxpy` wants.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376750/how-to-solve-systems-of-following-equations-using-matlab-or-python#comment9146638_4376750) posted under your now-deleted question still stands: the first sets of equations are linear in $\alpha_t,\beta_t$, and you can solve each pair in terms of $\theta$. Then you are left with two equations in $\theta$ alone, and must hope they have a common solution in $(0,1)$. So, before solving or optimizing, you need to decide how exactly you want to deal with the system being overdetermined.

Comment: @dxiv What do you mean by system being overdetermined (over/under-estimation of $\theta$?). I apologize if my question seems ignorant but I'm not too familiar with this topic and I'm not sure how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: Overdetermined means that you have more equations ($2T+2$) than unknowns ($2T+1$). Also, there are some cross-dependencies between the equations, for example the system has no solutions if $\,\sum c_t \ne 1\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Ah yes, in my problem $\sum_t c_t = 1$. What are some ways I can deal with the system being overdetermined?

Comment: With $\,\sum_t c_t=1\,$ one equation is redundant, so the system is no longer overdetermined. Under some additional assumptions, it can be shown that an eligible solution exists $\,\theta \in (0,1)\,$, but that part did not fit into a comment so I posted it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Too long for a comment*.) $\;$ Don't know that there is an advantage to formulate it as a multi-variate convex optimization problem, since it can be reduced to a single univariate rational equation.

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \alpha_t \cdot (1-\theta) + \beta_t\cdot \theta &= c_t \; &t = 1, \dots, T\\
> {\beta_t \cdot \theta^2 \over \alpha_t \cdot (1-\theta)^2 + \beta_t \cdot \theta^2} &= k_t\; &t=1, \dots, T
> \end{align}
> $$

Let $\,a_t = (1-\theta)\,\alpha_t\,$ and $\,b_t=\theta\,\beta_t\,$, then each pair of equations is a linear system in $\,a_t, b_t\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
a_t+b_t &= c_t
\\ \theta\, b_t &= k_t\,\big((1-\theta)\,a_t+\theta\,b_t\big)
\end{cases}
\;\;\iff\;\;
\begin{cases}
a_t+b_t &= c_t
\\ (1-k_t)\theta\, b_t &= k_t\,(1-\theta)\,a_t
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Eliminating $\,b_t\,$ between the equations:

$$
(1-k_t)\theta\,(c_t-a_t) = k_t\,(1-\theta)\,a_t
 \;\;\iff\;\; a_t = \frac{(1-k_t)c_t\theta}{(1-2k_t)\,\theta+k_t}
$$

Substituting the above in $\,\sum_t \alpha_t = 1\,$ gives the equation in $\,\theta\,$:

$$
1 = \sum_{t=1}^T \alpha_t = \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{a_t}{1-\theta} = \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{(1-k_t)c_t\theta}{(1-\theta)\big((1-2k_t)\,\theta+k_t\big)} = \frac{\theta}{1-\theta} \, \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{(1-k_t)c_t}{(1-2k_t)\,\theta+k_t}
$$

Let $\,f(\theta)\,$ be the RHS of the latter, with $\,f(0)=0\,$. Under the additional assumption that $\,c_t, k_t \in (0,1)\,$ the limit $\,\lim_{\theta \to 1-} f(\theta)=+\infty\,$, so the equation $\,f(\theta)=1\,$ has a root $\,\theta \in (0,1)\,$.

Comment: wow, thank you so much! I formulated as a convex optimization problem because I wanted to use existing optimization tools like Matlab or cvxpy to solve them. I did not know we could reduce the problem the way you have!

Comment: @MoneyBall Glad it helped. You'll still need a solver to get the solution to the last equation, but it's a good idea in general to try and simplify it by hand as much as possible before resorting to computer tools.

Comment: I completely agree with you that we need to simplify it as much as possible. This is actually my first time tackling such problem and I got lost as you could tell from me trying to solve it as a convex optimization problem.
I already solved it using python's `scipy.optimize` library - solved it in no time! Again, thank you so much for you help!!